# CentOS package not available

Tags: php, yum, centos5

I installed a CentOS 5.5 and the default php package is 5.1.6.
I want to install 5.2.9, so I added /etc/yum.repo.d/CentOS-Testing.repo

```
[c5-testing]
name=CentOS-5 Testing
baseurl=http://dev.centos.org/centos/$releasever/testing/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://dev.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-testing
```

**php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm** is available http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/RPMS/

So I tried: *yum clean all*, *yum search php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm*
--> Warning: No matches found for: php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm

What I am doing wrong ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've told yum to *ignore* this repository by setting `enabled=0` in the configuration.  You can either set:

```
enabled=1
```

Or:

```
yum --enablerepo=c5-testing ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that was so simple ! one more question: It only list the 5.2.10 and not the 5.2.9, I tried : yum install php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm --> No package php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm available.

Comment: I imagine that the more recent 5.2.10 package masks this version.  If you *really* want the older version, you can do (a) download the package locally (`wget http://dev.centos.org/centos/5/testing/x86_64/RPMS/php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm`) and then install it with yum (`yum install php-5.2.9-2.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm`).  This will pull in all the dependencies.